# sudo: apt-get: command not found

Tags: shell, command, sudo, apt-get

I am really struggling to get my head around terminal i keep getting commands not found what am i doing wrong?

I am trying to install ruby on the mac using this tutorial.
http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/

but i keep getting the error sudo: apt-get: command not found

```
Ben-Easts-iMac:~ Ben$ sudo
usage: sudo [-n] -h | -K | -k | -L | -V | -v
usage: sudo -l[l] [-AnS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-U username] [-u username|#uid]
            [-g groupname|#gid] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHnPS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u
            username|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AnS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u
            username|#uid] file ...
Ben-Easts-iMac:~ Ben$ sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full
Password:
sudo: apt-get: command not found
Ben-Easts-iMac:~ Ben$ sudo apt-get install ruby-full
sudo: apt-get: command not found
Ben-Easts-iMac:~ Ben$ sudo apt-get install ruby-full
sudo: apt-get: command not found
Ben-Easts-iMac:~ Ben$ sudo find / -name "apt-get" -print
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
sudo which apt-get
```

Can some please help me or give me an option to try to debug.

thanks

Comment: i am using an imac i have looked at macports but it only seems to have dmgs for “dmg” disk images for Snow Leopard, Leopard and Tiger
         as a legacy platform, will these work?

Answer (score 11):

`apt-get` is suitable for Linux based Ubuntu machines;  for MAC, try apt-get equivalent such as `Brew`

Answer (score 1):

are you using a linux debian flavored system ?

if you are on Mac OS (iMac make me think so), you will not be able to use aptitude as it simply doesnt exist on Mac os.

may I advice you to go to http://www.macports.org/ which is kind of the same system (but based on Unix port)

Comment: Hi Pierre i am on an imac i will go look at macports no thanks ;) do it give me a simialar apllication as terminal to use?

Comment: Yeah it is very similar in usage (sudo port install ruby19) would do what you want.

Comment: thanks i am installing xcode and i will then install macports, ill post back when im done cheers

Answer (score 0):

I managed to final get a install up and running what a pain.

I am running an imac with mac os x version 10.6.6

i had to first run this command in the terminal.
sudo port install ruby

ok great that then ran the install off ruby ok so after the install was complete i can the run this command.

rails new

which then created a project for me called "new" ok getting their.

next finding an editor to run rails- I installed netbeans seemed to be a good option.

next open new project and select ruby on rails application with existing sources, this then prompted me with the following error- that I don't have gems installed and to run this command.

```
gem install -v=2.3.5 rails
```

I have ran that command and got the following.

```
$ gem install -v=2.3.5 rails
WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 and
      /usr/bin aren't both writable.
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/Ben/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
Successfully installed rails-2.3.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-2.3.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-2.3.5...
```

ok so i then click ok on NetBeans and i am in with a project not sure whether gems is installed correctly tho, so gonna start learning ruby on rails now and ill report back with issues.

Hope this helps someone ;)

Comment: Still have trouble when i run the page i get Something went wrong on the server.
Check the server log for details! arrrrrrrrgggggggghhhhhh

Comment: try sudo gem install -v=2.3.5 rails

Answer (score -2):

sudo yum install  try using this

Comment: Since when CentOS/RHEL/Fedora's package manager is available on Mac's OS X?