# Mac cannot access port 22

Tags: linux, server, port, hpc

In conclusion, I cannot connect to port 22. To allow connection of port 22, I need to use `ufw` to set it up, but I was unable to do so on my machine.

I was trying to connect a server by running the command

```
ssh username@xx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

but I got the following errors

```
ssh: connect to host username@xx.xxx.xxx.xx port 22: Operation timed out
```

I googled it and figured out that the problem was related to port 22 connection, therefore I tried the following command as recommended.

```
sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
```

but I it seems like I need to install `ufw` first. I run the following command as recommended.

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
```

but It seems like I need to install `apt-get`. I tried to install it, but this post said Mac only use Brew. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231160/sudo-apt-get-command-not-found`. I tried to use brew but this is what I got.

```
brew install ufw

    xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "ufw".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get its complete history, run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

How do I fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Question is strange. It sounds like ufw is not a mac tool according to google. Did you try to connect via SSH from another PC? Maybe, problem is connected with server, not client?

Comment: I did connect it from another PC successfully

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I figure out that the problem is related to my VPN. I cannot connect to the port using my current VPN. However, I could connect to the port using another computer because it uses a correct VPN.